# href attribute doesn't work in Safari on iOS 13

Tags: javascript

I have some links on my page inserted through `map` method from an external file. They are working as expected on desktop in Chrome and Safari, but Safari on iOS 13 can't execute them.

```html
<section className="work__container__item__info">
  <h3 className="work__container__item__info__title">{name}</h3>
  <section className="work__container__item__info__btns">
    <button className="work__container__item__info__btns__btn">
      <a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href={demo}>
        Demo
      </a>
    </button>
    <button className="work__container__item__info__btns__btn">
      <a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href={github}>
        Github
      </a>
    </button>
  </section>
</section>
```

and snippet of file with data

```
github: "https://github.com/jack0wsky/weatherApp",
demo: "https://weatherapp-pniu2bsrf.now.sh/",
```

Does anyone know where I made a mistake?

Comment: Please attach your code so we can try and figure out the reasons it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem could be identified with the use of [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

It is forbidden to place an `<a>` inside a `<button>`. They are both things designed to be activated and do similar things. They are incompatible with each other.

Different browsers have different levels of error recovery for that mistake.